# Indent format as four space

Tags: emacs, elisp, indentation

all

I set my file indent policy in .emacs as following,

```
;; indent code settings
(setq-default indent-tabs-mode nil)
(setq default-tab-width 4)
(setq tab-width 4)
```

but it doesn't work for xml file, when I using 'C+M+\' to format xml file, the child node only indent 2 space than parent. I want to child node is 4 space indent than parent. I add below settings, this works as what I want.

```
(custom-set-variables
 '(nxml-outline-child-indent 4))
```

Why does first setting not work? and, another problem, is there a consistent way to do that for all code file?

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The amount of an indent-step is set by a variable with `-offset` in it's name.

As several xml-modes are around, check the major-mode for such, here its `sgml-basic-offset` with value 2 - which would need 4.

Also `indent-tabs-mode` must be `t`, if TAB character shall be used to fill the indent.